# Как с помощью yandex-geocoding-api получить получить координаты периметра района города?

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Стоит задача закрасить район города на карте, однако, метод геокодирования возвращает только две координаты района (Пример запроса, [https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=my_key&geocode=Россия](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=my_key&geocode=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), Ярославская область, Переславль-Залесский, 5-й микрорайон&format=json).

Возможно ли средствами Яндекс - API получить массив координат периметра района?
P.S. Похожие вопросы задавались около 8 лет назад, возможно что-то изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

Яндекс не отдаёт границы регионов.

Ранее в JS API был публичный модуль для отображения (не скачивания!) на карте регионов. Но оперативность обновления его границ была далеко от идеальной и со временем его закрыли совсем.

Подобные регионы раньше можно было скачивать на http://data.esosedi.org/ , но сейчас сайту что-то поплохело.